# How to write BytesWritable content to a file?

Tags: java, hadoop

```
if (value instanceof BytesWritable)
{
    BytesWritable b = (BytesWritable) value;
    byte[] bytes = b.getBytes();
    System.out.println(bytes.length);
    FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(
    new File(dstFolder, key.toString()), bytes);
}
```

My BytesWritable object *b* has the correct size of 269712 (It's an .exe file) . When I call getBytes(), the array *bytes* has a length of 5764153. So then when I try to write *bytes* to a the output file with writeByteArrayToFile, the content is different than the content in my BytesWritable object *b*.

Where is my mistake or what's the correct way to write BytesWritable content into a file?

I'm using hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BytesWritable doesn't shrink its byte array after you change the length, so when you call getBytes() you might get some junk after what you're interested in. In later versions of hadoop you can call [copyBytes()](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/BytesWritable.html#copyBytes%28%29) to get only the bytes up to the current length.

In earlier versions, you'll have to copy from the byte array returned by getBytes() up to the length returned by getLength().